# Prevent crash if button is clicked before selection in DefaultListModel?

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, actionlistener, defaultlistmodel

I'm using a DefaultListModel to select different names in a list. To select a name the user click on one of the name in the list so it get highlited and then confirm the selected name by pressing a button. My problem is if the user click on the button before a name is selected in the list, then it crash!

So far I have used this code, but it's not enough to prevent an crash

```
if(event.getSource() == buttonSelectCustomer && model1.getSize() > 0)
```

Is there a way to prevent a crash if user click the button without any selection? Thanks!

Comment: You're going to need to share the rest of the relevant code as well.

Comment: What does the stacktrace show?

Comment: add this to you condition (list.getSelectedIndex() != -1)

Comment: @3D-kreativ be sure that you to set correctly http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#selection, because you can set only one Item or you can determine in the Array of selected Items

Comment: Thanks Max! list.getSelectedIndex() != -1 was perfect!

Comment: And thanks for the advice mKorbel.

Comment: Also consider disabling the button until a selection is made. I urge @Max to post an answer.

Comment: +1 for @trashgod and usability comment

Comment: @trashgod how do I disable the button before a selection is made?

Comment: You use the `setEnabled` method of the button in combination with a selection listener on the list. Every time the selection changes, you check whether something is selected and adjust the enabled state accordingly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to you condition `(list.getSelectedIndex() != -1)`